Using \tl_put_right with grouping from latex3 explsyntax
Building on separate question (Using conditionals within \tl_put_right from latex3 explsyntax), I am attempting to use grouping to localise keys to a specific instance within a list. However, the grouping fails when there is a \tl_put_right; there is no output. However, without grouping, the keys are not reset and persist for all items:
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\keys_define:nn { itemj }
  {
    opt .tl_set:N = \l_itemj_options_tl,
    opt .initial:n = {},
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}{%
    %\group_begin:    
    \keys_set_known:nn { itemj } { #2 }
    \tl_put_right:Ne \l_tmpa_tl
    {
        \exp_not:N 
            \task 
                \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
                \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_itemj_options_tl
                {}
                {[\l_itemj_options_tl]}
        \exp_not:n 
        
        { #3 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #4 } }
    %\group_end:
    }


\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
  {
    O{} % optional options
    D(){1} % number of columns
  }
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpa_tl
  }
  {
    \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \l_tmpa_tl
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
  }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

Output:


well you then need a global variable, so \tl_gput_right:Ne \g_tmpa_tl etc. But better to not use the public \g_tmpa_tl but your own internal variable.

I'm not entirely sure about the purpose of collecting stuff in a global variable which you don't seem to use, but if you do want to collect it while keeping the options local, as Ulrike Fischer said, you need a global variable.
Note that expl3 uses a very precise naming syntax. If you have
\cs_new:Nn \harry_...

then harry should be your package/module name and all your variables should use it. In addition, your keys should belong to harry. If you want distinct sets of keys, use e.g. harry/itemj and harry/itemk or whatever.
Variables have names formed as follows
\<scope>_<module>_<description>_<type>

where <scope> is l, g or c and , in this case, we're assuming is harry.
 \tl_put_right:Nn \l_...

sets a variable locally.
 \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_...

sets a variable globally. Local variables should always be set locally; global only globally.
As I mentioned before, it is a bad idea to rely on pre-defined scratch variables for storage except when you have full control of everything for a brief time, because other people's code may use them, too. For example, tasks might use \l_tmpa_tl or \g_tmpa_tl. So it is better to define your own module-specific scratch variables.

Do please familiarise yourself with the syntax being used here and the way the functions you're using work. Once you do so, you will know from the names whether things act locally or globally, how their arguments are handled and how to name your own. This doesn't always make their behaviour predictable, but it typically makes it far more so than the names of typical LaTeX 2e commands - never mind TeX!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% assuming your package/module name is harry
% this should be used in every function an variable name

\tl_new:N \g_harry_itemj_tmpa_tl

% if you have multiple sets of keys sub-divide them like this
\keys_define:nn { harry / itemj }
{
  opt .tl_set:N = \l_harry_itemj_options_tl,
  opt .initial:n = {},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\itemJ}{s O{} m O{}}{%
  \group_begin:
    \keys_set_known:nn { harry / itemj } { #2 }
    \tl_gput_right:Ne \g_harry_itemj_tl
    {
      \exp_not:N \task
      \IfBooleanT{#1}{*}
      \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_harry_itemj_options_tl
      { } {
        [\l_harry_itemj_options_tl]
      }
      \exp_not:n { #3 \\ \textit{Solution:} ~ #4 }
    }
  \group_end:
}


\NewDocumentEnvironment{harrytasks}
{
  O{} % optional options
  D(){1} % number of columns
}
{
  \tl_gclear:N \g_harry_itemj_tl
}
{
  \harry_task_make:nnV {#1} {#2} \g_harry_itemj_tl
}
\cs_new_protected:Npn \harry_task_make:nnn #1#2#3
{
  \begin{tasks}[#1](#2) #3 \end{tasks}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \harry_task_make:nnn {nnV}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\title{Tasks Package Example with \texttt{NewDocumentCommand}}
\author{Your Name}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section*{Example Task Lists}

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}(4)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ[opt={(X)}]{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}[label=\alph*., label-format={\bfseries}](2)
  \itemJ{First item}
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
  \itemJ{Fourth item}
\end{harrytasks}

\medskip

\begin{harrytasks}
  \itemJ{First item}[This is the solution]
  \itemJ{Second item}
  \itemJ{Third item}
\end{harrytasks}

\end{document}

